# Using Python for quasi randomization

Tags: python, random

Here's the problem: I try to randomize n times a choice between two elements (let's say [0,1] -> 0 or 1), and my final list will have n/2 [0] + n/2 [1]. I tend to have this kind of result: [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0, until n]: the problem is that I don't want to have serially 4 or 5 times the same number so often. I know that I could use a quasi randomisation procedure, but I don't know how to do so (I'm using Python).

Comment: This is perfectly random in my book: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

Comment: You people need to stop saying "random" when you mean "some distribution that appears chaotic enough to me".

Comment: "I don't want to have serially 4 or 5 times the same number so often"  Why not?  That's how random works.  There's a 1/32 chance of seeing 5 1's in a row.

Answer (score 4):

To guarantee that there will be the same number of zeros and ones you can generate a list containing n/2 zeros and n/2 ones and shuffle it with `random.shuffle`.

For small n, if you aren't happy that the result passes your acceptance criteria (e.g. not too many consecutive equal numbers), shuffle again. Be aware that doing this *reduces* the randomness of the result, not increases it.

For larger n it will take too long to find a result that passes your criteria using this method (because most results will fail). Instead you could generate elements one at a time with these rules:

- If you already generated 4 ones in a row the next number must be zero and vice versa.
- Otherwise, if you need to generate x more ones and y more zeros, the chance of the next number being one is x/(x+y).

Comment: Of course, that algorithm breaks down if you generate all n/2 0's too quickly, and then the rest of the 1's will violate the "too many 1's in a row" constraint.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: Ah... good point, well spotted! This could be fixed but it might be more trouble to do it than its worth, depending on important the requirement is.

Comment: Of course that's only a problem with the third algorithm. The first two work, but don't quite meet the requirements. Neither does the accepted answer though, so I guess the requirements are more flexible than as stated in the question.

Comment: I tried filtering during shuffle, only to conclude a bare shuffle works the same... Good thing that my answer was de-accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) to randomize a list.

```
import random
n = 100
seq = [0]*(n/2) + [1]*(n-n/2)
random.shuffle(seq)
```

Now you can run through the list and whenever you see a run that's too long, swap an element to break up the sequence. I don't have any code for that part yet.

Comment: How would you decide *which* other element to swap to (just thinking about the idea)?

Comment: @ChristopheD, one reason I don't have code for that part is that I haven't figured out all the details yet :)

Comment: It's a wee bit harder than I first thought :D

Comment: +1 - I don't usually upvote duplicates but your answer adds something that mine doesn't have (source code) and I think that's worth a vote. :)

Answer (score 1):

Having 6 1's in a row isn't particularly improbable -- are you sure you're not getting what you want?

There's a simple Python interface for a uniformly distributed random number, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @clowny: Did you read http://docs.python.org/library/random.html or http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.uniform yet?  If not, why not?  If so, what's your specific question?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it. The first two functions are the actual implementation and the last function is for testing it.

The key is the first function which looks at the last N elements of the list where `N+1` is the limit of how many times you want a number to appear in a row. It counts the number of ones that occur and then returns 1 with (1 - N/n) probability where `n` is the amount of ones already present. Note that this probability is 0 in the case of `N` consecutive ones and 1 in the case of `N` consecutive zeros.

Like a true random selection, there is no guarantee that the ratio of ones and zeros will be the 1 but averaged out over thousands of runs, it does produce as many ones as zeros.
For longer lists, this will be better than repeatedly calling `shuffle` and checking that it satisfies your requirements.

```
import random


def next_value(selected):

    # Mathematically, this isn't necessary but it accounts for
    # potential problems with floating point numbers.
    if selected.count(0) == 0:
        return 0
    elif selected.count(1) == 0:
        return 1

    N = len(selected)
    selector = float(selected.count(1)) / N

    if random.uniform(0, 1) > selector:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def get_sequence(N, max_run):
    lim = min(N, max_run - 1)
    seq = [random.choice((1, 0)) for _ in xrange(lim)]

    for _ in xrange(N - lim):
        seq.append(next_value(seq[-max_run+1:]))
    return seq


def test(N, max_run, test_count):
    ones = 0.0
    zeros = 0.0

    for _ in xrange(test_count):
        seq = get_sequence(N, max_run)

        # Keep track of how many ones and zeros we're generating
        zeros += seq.count(0)
        ones += seq.count(1)

        # Make sure that the max_run isn't violated.
        counts = [0, 0]
        for i in seq:
            counts[i] += 1
            counts[not i] = 0
            if max_run in counts:
                print seq
                return


    # Print the ratio of zeros to ones. This should be around 1.
    print zeros/ones


test(200, 5, 10000)
```

Comment: I think the OP would appreciate if you could generalize on values and their numbers, but this is very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the smartest way, but it works for "no sequential runs", while not generating the same number of 0s and 1s.  See below for version that fits all requirements.

```
from random import choice
CHOICES = (1, 0)

def quasirandom(n, longest=3):
  serial = 0
  latest = 0
  result = []
  rappend = result.append

  for i in xrange(n):
    val = choice(CHOICES)
    if latest == val:
      serial += 1
    else:
      serial = 0
    if serial >= longest:
      val  = CHOICES[val]
    rappend(val)
    latest = val
  return result

print quasirandom(10)
print quasirandom(100)
```

This one below corrects the filtering shuffle idea and works correctly AFAICT, with the caveat that the very last numbers might form a run. Pass `debug=True` to check that the requirements are met.

```
from random import random
from itertools import groupby # For testing the result
try: xrange
except: xrange = range

def generate_quasirandom(values, n, longest=3, debug=False):
  # Sanity check
  if len(values) < 2 or longest < 1:
    raise ValueError

  # Create a list with n * [val]
  source = []
  sourcelen = len(values) * n
  for val in values:
    source += [val] * n

  # For breaking runs
  serial = 0
  latest = None

  for i in xrange(sourcelen):
    # Pick something from source[:i]
    j = int(random() * (sourcelen - i)) + i
    if source[j] == latest:
      serial += 1
      if serial >= longest:
        serial = 0
        guard = 0
        # We got a serial run, break it
        while source[j] == latest:
          j = int(random() * (sourcelen - i)) + i
          guard += 1
          # We just hit an infinit loop: there is no way to avoid a serial run
          if guard > 10:
            print("Unable to avoid serial run, disabling asserts.")
            debug = False
            break
    else:
      serial = 0
    latest = source[j]
    # Move the picked value to source[i:]
    source[i], source[j] = source[j], source[i]

  # More sanity checks
  check_quasirandom(source, values, n, longest, debug)

  return source


def check_quasirandom(shuffled, values, n, longest, debug):
  counts = []
  # We skip the last entries because breaking runs in them get too hairy
  for val, count in groupby(shuffled):
    counts.append(len(list(count)))
  highest = max(counts)
  print('Longest run: %d\nMax run lenght:%d' % (highest, longest))

  # Invariants
  assert len(shuffled) == len(values) * n
  for val in values:
    assert shuffled.count(val) == n

  if debug:
    # Only checked if we were able to avoid a sequential run >= longest
    assert highest <= longest

for x in xrange(10, 1000):
  generate_quasirandom((0, 1, 2, 3), 1000, x//10, debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to use this and modify the code in order to have, for a 100 element list, 25 of them with n = 2, 25 with n = 3...

Comment: Hmm, the `val  = CHOICES[val]` trick won't work then. Also, this version doesn't guarantee equal numbers of 0s and 1s. If that is a requirement, pick Mark **Ransom**'s answer instead and I'll show how to make it cap the number of serial runs.

Comment: Don't pick mine, I just realized looking back at the question that Mark Byers made the same suggestion long before I did.

Comment: OK, I think I see a way out, but it involves brute force and iteratively processing the list to break the runs. I'm not sure it's worth writing down, there must be a smarter way...

Comment: This is pretty much an implementation of Mark Byers answer: generate the sequence checking that you don't get serial runs, but do that in a shuffley way :)